# Deducing number from strong positive correlation of random variables

Tags: statistics, correlation

The following is known:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{50} x_i = 1250,
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{50} x_i^2 = 45000,
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{50} y_i = 3100,
\sum\limits_{i=1}^{50} y_i^2 = 250000$$

It is also known that there is a strong positive correlation between $x$ and $y$. Does this mean that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{50} x_i y_i$ must necessarily be greater than 45000?

My reasoning is that, since $\overline{x}=25$ and $\overline{y}=62$, because of a strong correlation, $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{50} x_i y_i \ge 77500$. However, we cannot deduce the exact sum of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{50} x_i y_i,$ can we?

Answer (score 1):

The product moment correlation coefficient $r$ is defined by:

$r=\frac{\Sigma xy-n\bar x\bar y}{\sqrt{\left (\Sigma x^2-n\bar x^2\right )\left (\Sigma y^2-n\bar y^2\right)}}$

To have 'strong positive correlation' we can say that $r$ must be greater than some critical value $r_c$. We also know that $r\le 1$

So $r_c \le \frac{\Sigma xy-n\bar x\bar y}{\sqrt{\left (\Sigma x^2-n\bar x^2\right )\left (\Sigma y^2-n\bar y^2\right)}}\le 1$

Thus $r_c \sqrt{\left (\Sigma x^2-n\bar x^2\right )\left (\Sigma y^2-n\bar y^2\right)}\le \Sigma xy-n\bar x\bar y\le \sqrt{\left (\Sigma x^2-n\bar x^2\right )\left (\Sigma y^2-n\bar y^2\right)}$

or $n\bar x\bar y +r_c \sqrt{\left (\Sigma x^2-n\bar x^2\right )\left (\Sigma y^2-n\bar y^2\right)}\le \Sigma xy \le n\bar x\bar y + \sqrt{\left (\Sigma x^2-n\bar x^2\right )\left (\Sigma y^2-n\bar y^2\right)}$

You are right that we can't say exactly what $\Sigma xy$ is, but we can give it bounds.

Comment: So if this is an upper bound, does this mean that either 25,000 or -25,000 could be correct answers for $S_{xy}$?

Comment: No. Using $S_{xy}=\Sigma xy-n\bar x \bar y$ we get $r_c \sqrt{\left (\Sigma x^2-n\bar x^2\right )\left (\Sigma y^2-n\bar y^2\right)}\le S_{xy} \le  \sqrt{\left (\Sigma x^2-n\bar x^2\right )\left (\Sigma y^2-n\bar y^2\right)}$

Comment: I think that gives about $28000 r_c \le S_{xy} \le  28000$. The lower bound depends on your choice of $r_c$